# Java job interview. How many objects are eligible for garbage collection?

Tags: java, reference, garbage-collection

Here is a typical Java job interview question. How many objects will be garbage collected by `System.gc();`?

I will use the following designations in the code:

- `a1` holds a reference to `A1`,
- `a2` holds a reference to `A2`,
- `mas` holds a reference to `Mas`, and
- `list` holds a reference to `List`.

**Used class.**

```
package com.mock;

public class GCTest {

    static class A {

        private String myName;

        public A(String myName) {
            this.myName = myName;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage.**

```
package com.mock;

import com.mock.GCTest.A;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a1 = new A("a1"); // A ref to A1. 1 ref in all.
        A a2 = new A("a2"); // A ref to A2. 2 refs in all.
        ArrayList<A> list = new ArrayList<A>(); // A ref to the empty ArrayList. 3 refs in all.
        list.add(a1); // The list has a1 holding a ref to A1 
        A[] mas = new A[2]; // A ref to an array; it has nulls in it. 4 refs in all.
        mas[0] = a2; // Now mas holds the ref to A2.
        a2 = a1; // a2 holds the ref to A1 
        clear(mas); // Nothing changed because methods deals with copies of parameters rather than with parameters themselves. 
        a1 = null; // a1 no longer holds the ref to A1
        a2 = null; // a2 no longer holds the ref to A1
        System.gc(); // Nothing should be garbage collected
    }

    private static void clear(A[] mas) {
        mas = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: When you already have an answer you should post it as such. So I would recommend you to create an answer yourself and move the second part of your question. When you are right, you get some upvotes. When people call it out for being wrong, you can still delete it.

Comment: The 'trick question' answer is: unknown, as calling `System.gc()` doesn't actually guarantee that a complete garbage collection cycle has been performed when it returns.

Comment: Why would `list` be garbage collected? It's still an empty `list` at the end and thus not valid for garbage collection.

Comment: In these kind of questions, it's never about "how many objects should be garbage collected" or "how many will be garbage collected" - it's about how many objects are *eligible* for garbage collection.

Comment: @eis Not necessarily. There is always the possibility that the interviewer just doesn't know what he's talking about.

Comment: @eis, I've already replaced _will be garbage collected_ with _should be garbage collected_. Since English isn't my first language, I can edit the title again

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev it's not just about the language - the concept is different as well. JVM doesn't make such guarantees about garbage collection, there's only stuff that are candidates for garbage collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is 0 because both `list` and the `mas` have elements holding references to `A1` (list) and to `A2` (mas).

I created three charts in order to simplify my answer. Rectangles correspond to the chunks in memory; circles correspond to objects. The gray arrows correspond to the references that no longer exist.

**Before a1 = a2.**

[image]

**After a1 = a2.**

[image]

**Neither a1 nor a2 hold references**

[image]

I could override `finilize()` for the class `A` to see what **is eligible** for gabage collection.

```
@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("finalize: " + myName);
    super.finalize();
}
```

Although I saw logs while I was testing the code, there is **no 100% guarantee** that memory is clear after calling [System.gc()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc%28%29)

> Runs the garbage collector.
>
> Calling the gc method suggests that the Java Virtual Machine expend
>   effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory
>   they currently occupy available for quick reuse. When control returns
>   from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine has made a best effort
>   to reclaim space from all discarded objects.

Comment: but then again, mas and list are not used after the System.gc() call, so an intelligent compiler or JIT could realize that he already can garbage collect all of the objects. No clue what the actual implementation does, but i wouldn't guarantuee that the objects are still in memory after that call.

Comment: If you consider an "intelligent compiler or JIT" the objects don't even need to be created.

Answer (score 3):

This may very well be a trick question.

What `System.gc()` does is dependend on the underlying garbage collector.

```
gc

public static void gc()

Runs the garbage collector.

Calling the gc method suggests that the Java Virtual Machine expend effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory they currently occupy available for quick reuse. When control returns from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine has made a best effort to reclaim space from all discarded objects.

The call System.gc() is effectively equivalent to the call:

     Runtime.getRuntime().gc()


See Also:
    Runtime.gc()
```

What you do know is that:

- Between 0 and "the number of Objects in your program" `Object`s will be garbage collected.
- There is a very high likelyhood that it will be between 0 and "the number of Objects that **should** be garbage collected".
- There is a relatively high likelyhood that it will garbage collect exactly "the number of Objects that **should** be garbage collected".

Comment: OK, let me rephrase my original question. How many objects **should** be garbage collected by `System.gc()`?